# PHP MYSQLi - Backup column data (into another table/column) before updating column

Tags: php, performance, mysqli, backup

I am working on a system which keeps track of what was in the field, prior to it being updated. I'd prefer using a table for the previous data, but am open to other options. This is some sample code which would accomplish the task :

```
<?php

$initial_value = $_POST['some_value'];
$id =231212213; // some id

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT column FROM table WHERE user=?")
$stmt->bindParam("s", $id);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($column);
$stmt->fetch();

if ($column !="") {
  //edit : it doesnt matter to me whether the data is moved into a new table or column
  $stmtA = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE another_table SET backup_column=? WHERE user=?");
  $stmtA->bindParam("ss", $column, $id);
  $stmtA->execute();

  $stmtB = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE table SET column=? WHERE user=?");
  $stmtB->bindParam("ss", $initial_value, $id);
  $stmtB->execute();
}

?>
```

Comment: Why not add a column called '**previous_val**'?

Comment: Doesnt matter to me whether the data will be moved to a new table or column. Either one will work

Comment: It makes more sense from a data usage perspective to add one column, rather than a table with **a)** a primary key, **b)** a foreign key and **c)** a value

Comment: like i said, it doesnt really matter. The older data will be kept for statistics. There will be hardly any queries against it. I was thinking a table because there are more than 20 columns that this needs to be done to, so just for clarity.

Comment: you could 1 query: update table set backup_column=column, column=? where user=? Unless you want to keep historic changes then use another table or a text field with a description of the changes

Comment: I am keeping historic changes. Each will be seperated with additional info with some kind of delimiter, and then referenced when necessary. I just need the to know the most efficient way of doing this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pure mysql commands solution which you could modify your code to do:

```
1.) CREATE TABLE new_table_name LIKE old_table_name
2.) INSERT INTO new_table_name SELECT * FROM old_table_name
```

Done. ;-)

This way you have an exact backup of your table previously, and joins are very easy to see the differences:

```
SELECT a.*, b.* FROM old_table a JOIN new_table b ON a.id=b.id WHERE <criteria>;
```

**EDIT**

```
UPDATE BACKUP SET COLUMN = (SELECT COLUMN FROM TABLE WHERE user_id=#) WHERE user_id=#;
```

Comment: assume the table is already created and the columns are set. I am trying to update the data from table to the other. In the backup table I will be appending the new data to the proper column. I believe this needs a `JOIN` but am unsure how to format it. Can you write the code?

Comment: Can you give a data example of what you want here? If row #1 is edited do you just want to update row #1 or make a copy of the whole table? My edit will update the appropriate row in the backup table. I also dont know if your table contains a unique user id for each row or there are many rows with teh same id.

Comment: i have new data coming in (from a form or whatnot), but before i update the current table with this new data, i want to get the data that is sitting there and move it to the backup table (which has the similar columns ("backup_" is in front)). Then as done normally, I want to update the original table with that form data.

Comment: Ok. My question is more about your data... Does each user of your system identified in your table by a user_id? If so will there only be one row in your table for each user of your system? Or does your table have one user with several rows in it.

Comment: each user is defined by a user_id (primary_key) in both tables

Comment: Great! :-) If that is the case then use my query in the "edit" section above. Execute this right before you update your main table.

EDIT: The reason I built the query the way I did is because you cannot join two tables on an update clause if the table being updated is also in the select part of your join. For example:

update backup set column = (select a.column from backup b join table a where user_id=#) would not work